# Patch RestCall update a password

Tags: rest, httpresponse, patch

I would like to create a patch rest call to update a login or a fullName or an email or a password of a user. And when updating email and password the oldPassword should be provided.
So I get through this solution:

> /api/users/{userId} as a URI

with body format :

```
{
    "login": "string",
    "fullName": "string",
    "email": "string",
    "oldPassword": "string",
    "newPassword": "string"
}
```

all body attributes are not required.

Now I am wondering what type of request should i get when sending only oldPassword in the jsonBody. is it **401 Unauthorize**d ??

Answer (score 1):

It should not be a 401, this request should require authentication with a Authenticate header. This should then fail which would result in a 401.

I think it should be a 400, bad request. Because they are not sending the correct message body.

"The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications."

It should however always contain some sort of explanation (if possible)

Check [here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) for more info on HTTP status codes